# Javascript: can I make two websites interact via javascript?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

This is a simplified example:
I use two online dictionaries, but each one has only a set of features I need. However it's a pain to click through both and type in the words in two places.
I would like to write my own javascript webpage, that loads elements from the two sites, i.e. the input field for the word, and then displays the results from the two sites on the same page.

My script would need to read elements from one page, and use that data to 
manipulate the other page.

When I tried researching this I encountered the same origin policy, but apparently chrome there's a workaround. My question is is this possible via browsers and javascript or would I have to look at a completely different technology like Python and webscraping.

Comment: If you don't control those website and if it's for a specific use, a reasonable solution would be to develop a browser extension to do that.

Comment: Which websites? I'll have a look. I have a simple idea already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just to consult the two websites for the same term at the same time, you could have your webpage with two `iframe`s and set their `src` attributes like the following:

```js
$("#search").click(function () {
    var term = $("#term").val();
    $("#dictionary").attr("src", "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/" + term);
    $("#free").attr("src", "https://www.thefreedictionary.com/" + term);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="term" type="text" placeholder="search dictionaries">
<input id="search" type="button" value="Search"><br>
<iframe id="dictionary" src="about:blank" style="width:45vw;height:500px;"></iframe>
<iframe id="free" src="about:blank" style="width:45vw;height:500px"></iframe>
```

The URL of the website is their API. Just look at the address bar after you've done a search on their site to find out how to construct it yourself.

**Bonus**

I myself use different websites like this, but via custom commands to automatically open multiple tabs in the browser (which you can also do via Javascript).

I use commands on linux like the following (declared in `.bashrc`):

```
function d {
    firefox "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/$1+$2+$3+$4+$5"&exit
}
```

which means, without firefox even being open, I can open a terminal (with a keyboard shortcut) and type `d test` to launch firefox and search a dictionary for `test`. If firefox is already running it'll be brought to the foreground and the website will open in a new tab.

In windows you can add batch files (`*.bat`) or command files (`*.cmd`) to do the same thing. In `c:\windows` you can create a file called `d.cmd` with:

```
start "" "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/%1+%2+%3+%4+%5"
```

then use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Win+R</kbd> to open the run dialog and type `d test`.

The run dialog used to be in the Start Menu, they've probably hidden it on your version of windows.

Comment: Thanks, that's really great. I have a more complicated issue, which is that I need autocompletion. Website 1 has an input field that does the autocompletion, so what I need is for my script to somehow grab the data from that and transfer it to the input field website 2. Ideally all this would be on one page so I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to somehow grab the input field from site 1 my own HTML, and then get the results from both sites onto that same page.This is the 1: http://dictionary.tovnah.com and 2: https://kheng.info/search/

Comment: To correct: "grab the input field from site 1 and put it into my own HTML". Now I'm thinking I could do 3 iframes, but ideally I would like to put the results into just one page so I can reformat it to display vertically next to each other. Is it possible w/o using iframes ?

Comment: I doubt the website will allow open access to their autocomplete API, and you can't reach into the `iframe` to pull out any data either because of ([Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)). But you could implement your own autocompletion if you get your hands on a dictionary file aith all the words in their.

Comment: Do you think I could load the document of the results into a javascript variable and display some element from the loaded DOM ? The problem is the first page with the autocomplete would be the HTML of website 1, am I able to run javascript on a loaded page, or would I have to write a browser extension ?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, I would like to load website one in my browser. Then run some javascript to load the results into two variables and display some of that while hiding most of the original webpage. Can I run javascript on a website loaded in the browser and manipulate it's DOM, or will I have to write a browser extension to do this?

Comment: @Marco If your still interested, you could also use [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) to execute a script when the dictionary result loads, read the term from the URL (or from the page) and then open the other site with the same term.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with JS if the dictionaries have endpoints you can interact with. (Or at least that would be the easiest). And most of them do. You can often enough simply google `dictionary name + API`.

If you have access to that you can fire off 2 requests to fetch data which you can then display on your page once it is back.

Comment: I understand thanks, these sites don't have APIs though because it's a rare language and small sites. I would have to deal with the DOM myself.